# UIAlertview is showing in portrait mode when screen is in landscape mode

Tags: ios8, orientation, alertview

I have an application that is configured to support Portrait mode only. But I have to show one screen (say abcViewController) in my application in landscape mode. When  abcViewController screen is pushed ,orientation changes from Portrait mode to Landscape mode. In that abcViewController screen  statusBar, all images ,buttons  are shown in landscape mode but UIAlertView is displayed in PortraitMode.
   This means everything on view changes to landscape mode in abcViewController  but UIAlertView doesn’t rotate to Landscape mode and remain in Portrait Mode.
I would like the UIAlertView to follow the rules of the containing view controller and show same orientation as statusBar.

[image]

Note: I m running my app on iOS 8.0 using Xcode 5.0 and I am searching for the solution which supports Xcode 5.0

Comment: Hi ajeet.cody,
Have you got any solution on this? If yes please reply me on my mail id: shripad.chidrawar20@gmail.com. Looking for positive reply. Thank in advance.

Comment: @shripad20 I have posted a answer. I hope this will help you. Let me know if you have any doubt. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I rotated `UIView` and status bar of this class programmatically for iOS 7 and earlier iOS versions,but I was having this problem of orientation problem in iOS 8, then I read a new change of iOS 8 which is related to orientation which is given below:

I ran the following code in both iOS 7 and iOS 8:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
BOOL landscape = (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
NSLog(@"Currently landscape: %@, width: %.2f, height: %.2f", 
      (landscape ? @"Yes" : @"No"), 
      [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 
      [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
```

The following is the result from iOS 8:

```
Currently landscape: No, width: 320.00, height: 568.00
Currently landscape: Yes, width: 568.00, height: 320.00
```

Comparing to the result in iOS 7:

```
Currently landscape: No, width: 320.00, height: 568.00
Currently landscape: Yes, width: 320.00, height: 568.00
```

so, I got to know [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size becoming orientation-dependent in iOS8.

After reading this new change of iOS 8 I created a new class for iOS 8, so you have two solutions for this issue.

Solution 1: You should use `UIAlertController` instead of `UIAlertView`.

Solution 2: You can create a new class for iOS 8 for which you are facing this orientation issue.

Comment: Thanks @ajeet for your solution. I was rotating the view forcefully but later I changed the implementation of rotation of view and it solved my problem.